# Open in Terminal item is missing for network shares

Tags: 22.04, files

I noticed something odd today. When I have a network share open, the context menu of the Files file browser in Ubuntu-22.04 is missing the "Open in Terminal" item.

With local folders, like home or Downloads, the item is there. But it is oddly not displayed for network drives.

Do I need to grant some special permissions to some snaps or anything?
Ubuntu used to be such an easy "it just works" OS. Why did this go away?

---

Here are two screenshots, one showing the Desktop (never mind it being empty), and one showing a network share.

[image: Local Folder]

The context menu, when right-clicking into the empty space of the network folder, is missing the "Open in Terminal" entry.

[image: Network Share]

---

The network share is mounted via "Other places", and entering a "smb://Something.Something" network address.

Comment: I am happy to answer your question (just doing some research), but please, lose the snark that it isn't a 'just works' OS. It's entirely likely this feature was taken away or didn't exist upstream in GNOME, not an Ubuntu-specific choice to spite users and make things harder.

Answer (score 3):

I've just checked my Ubuntu 23.10 workstation and Ubuntu 22.04.3 in a VM. They both have two options to launch a terminal on a remote (sftp) folder.

[image: File manager context window]

"Open in Remote Terminal" and "Open in Local Terminal". The first launches a terminal with an SSH session to the remote server. The second launches a local terminal in a gvfs folder which has the remote folder mounted under it.

[image: Two windows using remote and local terminal connection]

So the option is indeed there for sftp remote servers. Perhaps you are not mounting a server in the same way?